# Application Load Balancer on AWS for microservices

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have five microservices which are running on a diff-diff port, I have to implement an application load balancer on AWS. I have two scenarios:

1. Needs to be created 5 Target Group as per microservices -- I wonder if this will be complicated.
2. or can I create a rules in a particular listener  where I can define the path (port) base routing -- not sure about this.

What things can I try?

Comment: Do you use ECS? Can you explain more what is your use case?

Comment: no, i am not using ECS, I have 5 microservices which are running on the diff-diff port. how can i set up application load balancer for that

Answer (score 0):

You will need 5 target groups regardless of solution. You'd have a listener for HTTP and another for HTTPS. Then use a path based rule to forward the traffic to the appropriate target group.

See additional link:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-load-balancer-routing.html

Comment: ok but I have 5 microservices. Let's assume below are the 5 microservices.              App1 running on port 9001
App2 running on port 9002
App3 running on port 9003
App4 running on port 9004
App5 running on port 9005    in this case where will i decide the poer

Comment: The target group defines the port on the target host, the listener defines what the consumer can see. So the listener might be 443 HTTPS, and the target groups will be 9001, 9002, 9003, 9005 and 9005

Comment: Ok got it Thanks you so much

Comment: one more thing, I have created the target groups but it's showing this error "Health checks failed with these codes: [404]"  Shall I have to add the ALB security group in instance SG ?

Comment: Make sure the path that its resolving to returns something. path and port both needs to resolve something, you can also check status code(s) that should be returned for success too